# How do I find out how much of the provided data is in a column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I have the following data `('Toyota', 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Ferrari', 'Fiat')`. I want to see out of the 5 manufacturers I have listed, what is the percentage that the data appears in the `car_manufactures` tables at least once. In this example, the `match` rate is `80%` because all except `Fiat` manufacture appears at least once in the column. Hence, from the data, we provided, `80%` of the data appeared.

This is the `cars` table

| car_manufactures | boss |
| --- | --- |
| BMW | John |
| Toyota | Sam |
| Ferrari | Sarah |
| Audi | Paul |
| Toyota | Madi |
| Toyota | James |
| BMW | Sarah |

My desired result is

| column | table | match rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car_manufactures | cars | 80% |

In my attempt, I am unsure how to calculate the `match rate` and how I can select the `table_name` and `column_name`. I want to do this in pure SQL. I do not want to hard code the table name or column name, as well as hard code the any parts of the match rate.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME as table, COLUMN_NAME as column, '' as match
FROM cars
-- Unsure how to join the table ALL_TAB_COLUMNS to get the table name and column name
where car_manufactures in ('Toyota', 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Ferrari', 'Fiat')
```

Comment: How do you "have the data" (meaning, the five manufacturer names)? In your post you show that as a tuple of individual strings, one per manufacturer. What is that? Do you have a collection that you can pass to the query? Are they stored in a table? Is the user selecting them from a drop-down list at runtime? This is an important detail you forgot to tell us about.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know there are five, then something like this should do what you want:

```
select 'car_manufactures' as column, 'cars' as table,
       count(distinct car_manufactures) * 1.0 / 5
from cars
where car_manufactures in ('Toyota', 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Ferrari', 'Fiat');
```

Comment: But how can I get the column name and the table name in the select stable too? And what if I don't know there is 5?

Comment: @Coolio . . . You know the size of the list; yuou are starting with that.

Comment: I wanted to make the question simple and easy to understand. However, there are multiple items in the list which isn't easy to count.

Comment: @Coolio - What do you mean by "**get**" the column name and the table name? Don't you know them **before** you run the query? If you don't, that's crazy. That's not how relational databases are supposed to be used. You should know in advance what tables and what columns in those tables will have the info you need to analyze.